# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, apache, docker, virtualhost

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel con docker y lo estoy queriendo subir a hostinger por ssh (linux).

Lo que hice hasta el momento fue:

1. Agregue la ip del server a /etc/hosts
2. Instale docker e hice build.
3. Instale apache y configure 000-default de sites-availables con reverse proxy ya que apache utiliza el puerto 80:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>    
     ProxyPreserveHost On 
     ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
   ```

4.Parte del docker (la que interesa realmente:

```
http:
    build: http
    image: ${PROJECT_NAME}_http
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_http
    logging:
      driver: 'json-file'
      options:
        max-size: '200k'
        max-file: '10'
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/b612/public
      - HOME=/tmp
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-auth.sock
    volumes:
      - ./../:/var/www/html/b612
      - ./php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./php/conf.d/session.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/session.ini
      - ./http/conf/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    depends_on:
      - database
```

Al momento de entrar a la url del server aparece el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /www/aaa.com.ar/htdocs/includes/funciones.php:42 Stack trace: #0 /www/aaa.com.ar/htdocs/includes/funciones.php(107): server->connectdb() #1 /www/aaa.com.ar/htdocs/index.php(22): include('/www/aaa...') #2 {main} thrown in /www/aaa.com.ar/htdocs/includes/funciones.php on line 42

Comment: Este error: **mysql_connect() in** es ajeno totalmente a Laravel pues el mismo usa por debajo PDO para conectarse, revisa los archivos que te esta indicando el mensaje de error, pues el mismo se deriva de que usas las funciones *mysql_** las cuales son obsoletas ya

Comment: No @BetaM porque no tengo mysql instalado ni nada, estoy queriendo levantar el docker y tira eso

Comment: Pues como te menciono el error no tiene que ver con tu Laravel (según lo que dice la lectura del mismo), te esta avisando sobre otro archivo en la ubuicación ahi marcada por usar una función obsoleta y que desde PHP 7 se removió

Comment: Puedes mostrar el docker-compose completo por que hay algo ahi que no cuadra. Como te comentan `mysql_connect` fue eliminada de php. Tambien indica que version de Laravel y PHP estas utilizando.